# guid that is generated from string, is its value always same?

Tags: c#, guid

if i use the simple code below to generate a Guid from a string, is this Guid's value always same whenever i generate it with same string?

```
Guid Guid1 = new Guid(Data.GetHash(txtName.Text.Trim()));
```

Comment: You can debug it easily and find it out,

Comment: Depends on your `Data.GetHash` method I suppose

Comment: Give it a go and see?!

Comment: A GUID is not a collection of arbitrary bytes. What you're producing there is not a valid GUID and not guaranteed any kind of "global uniqueness". Store the hash as what it is: a collection of bytes (`byte[]`, `VARBINARY`, etc.)

Comment: @DavidG A GUID is not *just* a collection of bytes.  It's a specific type of collection of bytes that has additional requirements.  Requirements not met in this code.

Comment: @DavidG No, that's literally what Jeroen's comment said.  I just repeated it.

Comment: DavidG: yes -- but a GUID is not a collection of *arbitrary* bytes. Even GUIDs that use random bits only have 122 of those bits random, not 128, as a few are reserved to indicate type and version. The more salient point is indeed that the expectations of global uniqueness aren't met by pouring a hash into a GUID mold, so I won't press the issue. :-P

Comment: "Requirements not met in this code." How do we know that? Maybe the GetHash function is defined as simply: `return Guid.NewGuid();` I think we can all agree the question needs some significant clarifications.

Comment: @aquinas: it's not defined as that because `Guid` doesn't have a constructor that takes a `Guid`. You're technically correct (best kind of correct!) but the chance that `GetHash` just so happens to generate a proper GUID or its constituent bytes based on a string (?) is negligible. I think we can safely take a potshot at the most likely scenario...

Comment: @JeroenMostert: sure, you can pass a string to the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Guid__ctor_System_String_). If that's the case and it generates a valid Guid it will always create the same if you pass the same Guid as input.

Comment: @JeroenMostert. Touche. I should have said `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`.

Comment: @Rango: I meant the argument to `GetHash`, not the fact that you can construct a GUID from its string representation. A GUID-generating function that depends on an input value is almost certainly not "globally unique"! (I mean, it's *possible*, but I will eat my hat if that turns out to be the case.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: OP hasn't asked if it's "globally unique" but if it's "always same whenever i generate it with same string". Well, the question doesn't make much sense and a lot details are missing.

Comment: @Rango: oh, I'm sure it is -- that's not what my comments were about. A straightforward answer to the question ("we don't know, post the code of `GetHash`") followed by the likely "yes you're right" would not address the issue that this is a bad idea.

Comment: See also [RFC 4122](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-4.1) for a description of the internal structure of a GUID/UUID.

Comment: The question is not very clear. If you're asking if the guid constructor that takes in a string is deterministic, meaning it will provide the same guid for the same input every time, than the answer is yes (probably depending on run time environment properties such as framework version etc').  However, the `GetHash` method of your `Data` object we know nothing about - it might be deterministic and it might not be - so it's up to you to check this.

Answer (score 1):

Even the Version 4 GUID algorithm (which basically says "set the version to 4 and fill everything else with random or pseudo-random numbers") is not guaranteed to be unpredictable, because the algorithm does not specify the quality of the random number generator (And the generator is not cryptographically strong).

**If you want a random number generator, then use a random number generator.**

Answer (score 0):

If you review the constructor for the Guid() object you'll see that it takes in specific formats for the string and converts that to a Guid object.

The same string in should produce the same Guid() output.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=netframework-4.7.2